# File will not open in MQL4

Tags: file, mql4

I was hoping someone could look at my code and tell me why it won't open a file.
This is in meta-editor, the software for MQL4. Everything else runs correctly. Also no errors are given. It simply will not open a file. The value of Handle is one when a file is opened. This function works fine in MQL5, not in MQL4. Is this an issue with MQL4 exclusively or is it something with my code

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                  DailyReport.mq4 |
//|                        Copyright 2018, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2018, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict

int OnStart()
  {

  int Handle;
  Handle = FileOpen("Indicator Output", FILE_WRITE|FILE_TXT);

  if(Handle == INVALID_HANDLE){
      Alert("Error while opening file");
      return(-1);
  }

  int count = 0;
  int end_value = count + 100;

  double open_value; 
  while (count < end_value){

   string string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, final_string;
   double values[5]; 

   values[0] = iMomentum(0, 0, 14, 0, count); //calculated at closing
   values[1] = iStochastic(0, 0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, count);
   values[2] = iMA(0,0, 14, 0, 0, 0, count); //this is calculating at close
   values[3] = iMFI(0, 0, 14,count);
   values[4] = iOpen(0, 0, count);

   open_value = iOpen(0, 0, count + 1);

   if (values[0] >= 100){
      values[0] = 1;
   }
   else{
      values[0] = 0;
   }

   if (values[1] >= 50){
      values[1] = 1;
   }
   else{
      values[1] = 0;
   } 

   if (values[2] >= values[4]){
      values[2] = 1;
   }
   else{
      values[2] = 0;
   }   

   if (values[3] >= 50){
      values[3] = 1;
   }
   else{
      values[3] = 0;
   }   

   if (values[4] >= open_value){
      values[4] = 1;
   }
   else{
      values[4] = 0;
   }   

   string1 = IntegerToString(values[0], 1, " ");
   string2 = IntegerToString(values[1], 1, " ");
   string3 = IntegerToString(values[2], 1, " ");
   string4 = IntegerToString(values[3], 1, " ");
   string5 = IntegerToString(values[4], 1, " ");

   final_string = string1 + " " + string2 + " " + string3 + " " + string4 + " " + string5;
   printf(final_string);

   FileWrite(Handle, final_string);

   count = count + 1;
  }
  FileClose(Handle);
  return(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`File` functions work same in both MQL4 and MQL5. First, you should check the reason why you cannot open a file (otherwise you wont have any error as you wrote).

```
if(Handle==INVALID_HANDLE){
   Alert("failed to open file. error=",GetLastError());
   return;}
```

Next, file name should be passed with extention, otherwise it might be a problem to open it in editor.
    string fileName="Indicator Output.txt";
    int handle=FileOpen(fileName, FILE_WRITE|FILE_TXT);

The main reason might be that you opened a file and forget to close it while working on your code. The easiest way to check that is to close MT4, reopen and try the script again. All opened by MT4 files are closed when MT4 shutdown. If that does not help - check the error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I honestly was not expecting to get one so quickly. You gave me a lot of information I did not know about MQL4. It turns out the file was not being saved to where I thought it was supposed to be saved. Had to do a search of PC to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips:

- The OnStart event handler is type void. `void OnStart(){}`
- The while loop can be improved with a for loop
- You're opening your file as txt file without an appropriate file
  extension. i.e. `.txt`, and you're using FileWrite which is intended
  for csv files. You might want to have a look at the docs and open the
  file as a csv and use FileWrite the way it is intended, to automatically insert 
  delimiters.
- You can optionally use the CFile object to work with files since it automatically closes 
  files.
- You don't need to use an array to temporarily store indicator values. It's confusing. Instead use descriptive variable names.
- ternary statements can greatly simplify and shorten your code.

This is how it looks when it's refactored.

```
#property strict

#include <Files\File.mqh>
#include <stdlib.mqh>

void OnStart()
{
   CFile file;
   file.Open("indicator_output.csv", FILE_WRITE|FILE_CSV, ',');
   if(file.Handle() == INVALID_HANDLE){
      Print("FileOpenError: ", ErrorDescription(_LastError));
      return;
   }
   for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
      double mom = iMomentum(NULL, 0, 14, 0, i); //calculated at closing
      double sto = iStochastic(NULL, 0, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, i);
      double sma = iMA(NULL, 0, 14, 0, 0, 0, i); //this is calculating at close
      double mfi = iMFI(NULL, 0, 14, i);
      double open = iOpen(NULL, 0, i);
      double prev = iOpen(NULL, 0, i + 1);  
      uint row_bytes = FileWrite(file.Handle(),
         mom >= 100   ? 1 : 0,
         sto >= 50    ? 1 : 0,
         sma > open   ? 1 : 0,
         mfi >= 50    ? 1 : 0,
         open >= prev ? 1 : 0
      );
      if(row_bytes == 0){
         Print("FileWriteError: ", ErrorDescription(_LastError));
         break;
      }
   }
   Alert(StringFormat("%s written with a size of %d bytes.",
      file.FileName(),
      file.Size()
   ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check to see if your File exists.

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                  FileIsExist.mq4 |
//|                        Copyright 2019, MetaQuotes Software Corp. |
//|                                             https://www.mql5.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright 2019, MetaQuotes Software Corp."
#property link      "https://www.mql5.com"
#property version   "1.00"
#property strict
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnStart()
  {
     string terminal_data_path=TerminalInfoString(TERMINAL_DATA_PATH);
     string filename     = "teste2.txt";
     int fileHandle      ;    

     if(FileIsExist(filename,0))
       {
          Print("Specified File Has");
          fileHandle     =    FileOpen(filename , FILE_WRITE|FILE_TXT);
          FileWriteString(fileHandle,"teste");  
          FileClose(fileHandle); 
          Print("Write to Existing File Completed");

       }else
          {
               Print("File Not Available, Regenerating....." );
               fileHandle     =    FileOpen(filename , FILE_READ|FILE_WRITE|FILE_TXT);
               FileWriteString(fileHandle,"Writing to Newly Created File Completed - teste     \n");  
               FileClose(fileHandle); 
               Print("Writing to Newly Created File Completed");
          }

  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```